# wwwroot is not displayed in visual studio solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am building a web application.
I would like to place a html.index file in the wwwroot directory of my project solution to be able to build. However, wwwroot directory does not show in visual studio 2019.
Does anybody understand why this is happening

Comment: No. Not familiar with it. Have you tried adding the directory? What kind of app are you making?

Comment: Angular application but, a basic console asp.net application does not have the wwwroot. Weird. I did not have that in the old visual studios

Comment: I started from scratch and I added the directory manually and the html.index manually and I could make it work. Thanks